# 100 Gambles of Roulette

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability, gambling

I am stuck on the following problem:
You go to Las Vegas with $\$1000$ and play roulette $100$ times by betting $\$10$ on red each time.
Compute the probability of losing more than $\$100$. Hint: Each bet you have chance 18/38
of winning $\$10$ and chance 20/38 of losing $\$10$.

So essentially this is recurring 100 times.  Now each time you do it you have an 18/38 chance of winning and 20/38 chance of losing.  You have a greater chance of losing than winning, so based on speculation you need to lose 56/100 in order to lose more than $\$100$, to counterbalance your winnings . How would I set up an equation to solve for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please accept my answer if it is sufficiently detailed for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical Bernoulli experiment:
You already mentioned that we need to loose at least $56$ times to loose more than $100\$$. Let $X$ describe the number of times you loose. We want to compute $P(X > 56) = 1 - P(X \leq 56)$.  We also have:
$$P(X \leq 56) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\ 56}{100 \choose k}\left(\frac{18}{38}\right)^{100-k} \left(\frac{20}{38}\right)^{k}\space\space\approx 0.7805$$  which is the probability that we loose at most 56 times. Thus we finally obtain $1-0.7805 = 0.2195 = 21.95\%$ as our end result.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @rkong no problem, good to hear that I could help!